# In alert text are coming as uppercase though no property is added in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an alert which is specified  as below , and its showing alert is just a bool

```
.alert("Do you want to delete the event and its details?", isPresented: $showingAlert)
```

[image]
But its coming always as bold

Comment: Do you have a .textCase(.uppercase) modifier somewhere?

Comment: no where i have added that

Comment: cannot be reproduced, all works well for me in my tests, no uppercase of the text, but the text looks bold. I think this is what Apple wants to use.

Comment: strange I want the sentenced case

Comment: you are not making sense here, are you saying now you **want** the text to be uppercase?

Comment: no I want the text to be displayed as it is  written, First letter of the text is uppercase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were seeing a similar issue in our app. We had a standard `.alert()` configured on a view in a `List` which would occasionally (about 10-30% of the time) display in all caps for no apparent reason.

Adding a `.textCase(nil)` call *after* the `.alert()` modifier seemed to resolve the issue for us.

```
someView
    .alert(/* configure alert */)
    .textCase(nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. For me, the culprit was where I had placed the `.alert` modifier.

My code looked something like this:

```
List {
   Section(header: ..., footer: ...) {
      ...
   }
   .alert(...)
   .confirmationDialog(...)
}
```

I solved the problem by putting the `.alert` directly on the list like this:

```
List {
   Section(header: ..., footer: ...) {
      ...
   }
   .confirmationDialog(...)
}
.alert(...)
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

try this example code to display your alert with the text `...as it is written, First letter of the text is uppercase.`

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show alert") { showingAlert = true }
            .alert("Do you want to delete the event and its details?", isPresented: $showingAlert, actions: {})
    }
}
```

Comment: did my answer not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
       let logout = UIAlertController(title: "Logout", message: 
      "Are you sure you want to logout?", preferredStyle: 
         UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        logout.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        logout.dismiss(animated: true)
        }))
        
        present(logout, animated: true, completion: nil)
```